# Reapply chosen after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-chosen

I am developing an ASP.NET website. I am using the chosen jQuery dropdownlist. It was working great. Here's the code...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
    $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true }); 
</script>
```

After I add an UpdatePanel, upon postback, the dropdownlist's didn't work anymore. (Reverted to standard dropdownlist.) I researched the issue and based on my research I wrote this code, which doesn't work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  alert("1");

  $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
  $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true }); 

  $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("2");
      // bind your jQuery events here initially
      $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
      $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true }); 
      alert("3");
  });

  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

  prm.add_endRequest(function() {
      alert("4");
      // re-bind your jQuery events here
      $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
      $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true }); 
      alert("5");
  });

  alert("6");
</script>
```

Please don't laugh. I don't write much jQuery/js as you can see. Haha :)

Basically, I was trying to reapply the chosen effect with the above code. But, now, it doesn't even apply the effect in the initial load of the page. Could you please help me with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1- first add your js script inside function

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function ChosenDropdown() {
            $(".chzn-select").chosen();
            $(".chzn-select").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true }); 
        }

    </script>
```

2- register you js script on every postback using ScriptManager.registerStartupScript:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "ChosenD", "ChosenDropdown()", true);

    }
```

thats all ,, 
regards